# Charts: Value of type 'ChartData' has no member 'getDataSetByIndex'

Tags: swift, charts

I updated charts from 3.6.0 to 4.0.1 and i am getting this error:

Value of type 'ChartData' has no member 'getDataSetByIndex'

My code:

```
if let data = altimetriaChartView.data, data.dataSetCount > 1, let lineChart: LineChartDataSet = data.getDataSetByIndex(1) as? LineChartDataSet {

}
```

How can i solve that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing it like an ordinary swift array instead,

```
data[1] as? LineChartDataSet
```